# If Else Statements in Cypress

Tags: if-statement, cypress

I have problem with `if-else` in cypress. I have 3 questions. And the questions is not consistent, always change. So I wanted to set an answer for specific question. The error is, whenever the question B appear, cypress cant skip the question A and it stops. Cypress didn't read my if and else, and I can't understand, why it happens.

Here is my code:

```
let disabled = null;

cy.contains("What is your dream car brand?").then(() => {
  disabled = true;

  cy.get("input[name=securityQues]").type("Ferrari");

  cy.end();
});

if (disabled == false) {
  cy.contains("What is your favorite movie?").then(() => {
    cy.get("input[name=securityQues]").type("Forrest Gump");
  });
} else {
  cy.contains("Where is your favourite place to vacation?").then(() => {
    cy.get("input[name=securityQues]").type("Japan");
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe the problem? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Here I have 3 questions. And the questions is not consistent, always change. So I wanted  to set an answer for specific question. The error is, whenever the question B appear, cypress cant skip the question A and it stop. Cypress didnt read my if and else. Why cypress cant read my if else part?

Comment: I think you want to use jquery to test for the various texts, e.g `let carQuestion = Cypress.$('div:contains("What is your dream car brand"); if (carQuestion)...`.

Comment: `cy.contains(..)` has a built-in test which fails when the text is not present.

Comment: A better way is to break it down into separate tests for each question, and control which question shows via fixture.

Comment: Ok,I got the solution already. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another way to find your main element with a question. `.contains` in this case will not work. Try to use `.get('css-selector')` and then you can appropriate access that element. See an example here: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/cypress/support/timepicker.po.ts#L117

Answer (score 0):

Doing conditional testing on user interfaces is completely discouraged as your tests will never be deterministic. I'd tell you to try to find a workaround to your way of testing what you want to test.

Here there is a nice read on that https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#The-problem